# "Empty reply from server" when trying to run webpack-dev-server inside a docker container with docker-compose on windows running docker-toolbox

Tags: node.js, go, docker, docker-machine, docker-toolbox

I am having problems accessing a react container run with docker-compose inside docker-machine. I can curl the webpage inside the container, but I cannot access it inside docker-machine (or on the host's browser for that matter). The backend Golang container can be accessed from docker-machine and from the host's browser (as seen in the snippets, it returns a *404 not found*).

In the docker-compose logs everything seems to be running smoothly, webpack-dev-server runs as expected, I just can't access it from outside the container.

I am using docker toolbox for windows.

Best to additionally describe the problem with some snippets.

**Docker-compose file:**

```
version: '2'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    server:
        build: ./server
        command: gin
        volumes:
            - ./server:/go/src/app
        ports:
            - "8080:3000"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    client:
        build: ./client
        command: npm start
        volumes:
            - ./client:/usr/src/app
            # mount node_modules as a workaround for it disappearing
            # after adding /client as a mounted folder
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
        ports:
            - "9000:3000"
```

**Dockerfile for the node container:**

```
FROM node:6.5.0-slim

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
ENV NODE_ENV development
RUN npm install
```

**Output of the following commands inside docker-machine (default):**

> docker@default:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -L -n

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.19.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.18.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.19.0.2           172.19.0.2           tcp dpt:3000
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.19.0.3           172.19.0.3           tcp dpt:3000

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080 to:172.19.0.2:3000
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9000 to:172.19.0.3:3000
```

*Here comes the main problem:*

> docker@default:~$ curl 0.0.0.0:9000

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

> docker@default:~$ curl 0.0.0.0:8080

```
404 page not found
```

> docker@default:~$ docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
           NAMES
f93fd1833de2        goreacttodo_client   "npm start"              32 minutes ago      Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:9000->
3000/tcp   goreacttodo_client_1
ff1fa9c33b05        postgres             "/docker-entrypoint.s"   3 days ago          Up 5 minutes        5432/tcp
           goreacttodo_postgres_1
e4581f8e368b        goreacttodo_server   "gin"                    3 days ago          Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->
3000/tcp   goreacttodo_server_1
```

Output of the following commands inside the node container:

> root@f93fd1833de2:/usr/src/app# curl localhost:3000

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body lang="en">
<div id="react-app"></div>
<script src="/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body></html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Webpack development server by default listens on localhost only.

If you want to expose it's port outside of Docker container you need to explicitly specify host to listen to:

> webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80

Comment: By the way, same thing if using Node's `http` module. The `hostname` in the `listen()` method should be `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` so it works outside the container also, when doing port mapping.